# Modelbinding lists

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, modelbinders, viewdata

I got a controller action like

```
public class Question {   
   public int Id { get;set; }
   public string Question { get;set; }
   public string Answer { get;set; } 
}

public ActionResult Questions() 
{   
  return View(GetQuestions()); 
}

public ActionResult SaveAnswers(List<Question> answers) 
{  
  ... 
}
```

the view> looks like:

```
<% for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { %>   
 <div>
  <%= Html.Hidden(i.ToString() + ".Id") %>
  <%= Model[i].Question %>
  <%= Html.TextBox(i.ToString() + ".Answer") %>
 </div> 
<% } %>
```

Obviously this view doesn't work. I'm just not able access the list in the view.

The documentation for this also is outdated, it seem a lot of the functionality around modelbinding lists where changed in the beta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is not to use the html helpers.

```
<% for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { %> 
  <div>
     <input type="hidden" name="answers[<%= i %>].Id" id="answers_<%= i %>_Id" value="<%= Model[i].Id %>" />
     <input type="text" name="answers[<%= i %>].Answer" id="answers_<%= i %>_Answer" value="<%= Model[i].Answer %>" />
  </div> 
<% } %>
```

Not very pretty, but works. The important thing is that Name and Id need to be different.
Name is allowed to have "[", "]" but id isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711184/asp-net-mvc-example-of-editing-multiple-child-records/) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798127/more-complexreal-life-modelbinding/). Also [this blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx).

**Edit :** As for accessing the model in the view. Are you sure you declared your with the following attribute?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<List<Namespace.Question>>" %>
//Assuming the GetQuestions() method returns a list of question objects.
```

Comment: Those posts are mostly about getting your data into a model after a post. I'm problem is that i don't get the values out from the model when rendering the first view.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the question at first. I edited my answer after your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Scott Hanselman's post probably holds the answer. However it appears that you are trying to tie you view references to an anonymous object by returning in the post `...0.Answer=answer...`

You should instead I believe be tying your fields to the `List answers refering to the answers[index].Answer.

Try the following:

```
<% for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { %>   
 <div>
  <%= Html.Hidden("answer["+i.ToString() + "].Id", Model["+i.ToString() + "].Id) %>
  <%= Model[i].Question %>
  <%= Html.TextBox("answer["+i.ToString() + "].Answer", Model["+i.ToString() + "].Answer) %>
 </div> 
<% } %>
```

Richard