# How to use two instances of the same .ascx in the same page in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelbinders

I have two instances of an `Address.ascx` control in an ASP.NET MVC page.

```
   <h1>Shipping Address</h1>
   <% Html.RenderPartial("Controls/AddressControl"); %>

   <h1>Billing Address</h1>
   <% Html.RenderPartial("Controls/AddressControl"); %>
```

Of course, with the code exactly like this I'll end up with the same IDs for each field in the address. I can easily append a string to the ID of the fields so I'd have `'Street1_billing'` and `'Street1_shipping'`, but I'm not clear how to map this to the model.

Whats the best solution to mapping a model to an array of items (in this case only 2). 
I'm not aware of any ASP.NET 'out of the box' solution for this.

Note: This is slightly similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881838/modelbinding-lists) and I could use [this solution from Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx), but its not exactly what I want. In my case I know I have two items, so its essentially a 2 item array but I'm wondering if there is a slightly more elegant solution.

*PS. I'm sure this has been asked many times before, but I just cant seem to put in the right search terms. Please link this question if you're aware of dupes!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a ViewModel

```
OrderCheckoutViewModel
{
    public Address ShippingAddress{get;set;}
    public Address BillingAddress{get;set;}
}
```

The values of formelements are mapped to the right Member of the ViewModel if they have the form

```
<input type="text" name="ShippingAddress.StreetAddress1"><input>
```

There is no easy and elegant way to come from StreetAddress1 to ShippingAddress.StreetAddress1.
My address model has the form:

```
public class Address
{
    String StreetAddress1 { get; set }
    String StreetAddress2 { get; set }
    String City { get; set }
    String State { get; set }
    String Zip { get; set }
    String InstanceName{ get; set }
}
```

I set the InstanceName to the Name of the property (ShippingAddress).

Then the form elements are defined in this form

```
<input type="text" name="<%=Model.InstanceName%>.StreetAddress1"><input>
```

The place of the ascx looks uncommon. Any reason why you dont put it in Shared and access it by

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("AddressControl",Model.ShippingAddress); %>
```

?

Comment: thanks. this looks the cleanest solution so far. i hadnt realized the modelbinder was this clever :-) and as far as the .ascx location is concerned i'm writing a shopping cart within an existing application nad i want to keep the shopping cart controls as separate as possible.

Comment: That guy is clever indeed. One thing I still have not seen is if you can map a value from the route with the same kind of syntax.

Answer (score 4):

First, add an **Address** class to the model.

```
public class Address
{
    String StreetAddress1 { get; set }
    String StreetAddress2 { get; set }
    String City { get; set }
    String State { get; set }
    String Zip { get; set }
}
```

In **Address.ascx**, you need a line at the top that inherits the Address model, like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyProject.Models.Address>" %>
```

In the **controller for the main view**, push your two addresses into the ViewData.

```
Address myAddressObject1 = new Address
{
   AddressLine1 = "123 Anywhere Street",
   // ..etc.  Same with MyAddressObject2.  Or, just populate from database.
}

ViewData["Address1"] = myAddressObject1;
ViewData["Address2"] = myAddressObject2;
//
// do other stuff as needed
//
Return View();
```

In your **main view**, call your two Address subviews like this:

```
<%= Html.RenderPartial("Address", ViewData["Address1"]) %>
<%= Html.RenderPartial("Address", ViewData["Address2"]) %>
```