# Passing Html Element to the Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can I pass a HTML element to a controller action. Let's say I have the following element:

```
<table id="list"></table>
```

How do I pass this table into the controller action? Also will it be automatically converted to HtmlTable object?

Comment: The view should be responsible for presentation, not the controller, so it is possible that You Are Doing It Wrong. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

You can only pass that as a string, it won't be converted to HtmlTable object.

Comment: Thanks! Also, I think the controller action cannot be generic type Foo<T> (not sure why!!) How can I pass a list to a controller method like List<Product>.

Comment: @OrbMan, 

Actually I thought that I can pass the HTML element to the controller and then export the element to excel. I can do the same if I can pass the List<T>.

Comment: @azamsharp, Check this question for working with collections : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/711184/asp-net-mvc-example-of-editing-multiple-child-records/

Answer (score 0):

You are not suppose to pass any UI elements from controller to view. If you can elaborate more of your scenerio maybe I can help

Comment: Actually I was trying to find a way to send the Table from View to the Controller and then Controller can forward it to the ExportToExcelService which will then export the Table. But I ended up just passing the list to the service and then bind the list with GridView control and then exporting the GridView control to Excel.

Comment: And here is the article that talks about this: 
http://highoncoding.com/Articles/566_JQuery_jqGrid_Export_to_Excel_Using_ASP_NET_MVC_Framework.aspx