# ASP.NET MVC Model Binders. Call a controller with an array of objects parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to have the following signature of a MVC controller.

```
public ActionResult Create(Persons[] p)
{

}
```

Is it possible to have something like this?

EDIT:
Let's say I would like to obtain an array of person objects by submitting a list of names separated by a special symbol.
For example I submit a form

```
<form>
   <input name="person_name">Max|Alex|Andrew</input>
</form>
```

I suppose it should be done by implementing a IModelBinder interface but I didn't find any example how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh I've found how to do this.

In the Global.asax file in the Application_Start() function should be written:

```
ModelBinders.Binders(typeof(Person[])) = new PersonBinder();
```

In this manner a custom binder is registered.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711184/asp-net-mvc-example-of-editing-multiple-child-records/712817#712817) for how to get collections binded by the `DefaultModelBinder`.

Comment: Yes, but as long as you follow the pattern which the DefaultModelBinder understands, you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

I think this kind of thing will work

```
<input type="text" name="Person[1].name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you may need to play around with [a custom controlleractioninvoker](http://lostintangent.com/2008/07/03/aspnet-mvc-controlleractioninvoker-part-1/).

or just a plain [modelbinder](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Model_Binders_in_ASPNET_MVC.aspx)

Andrew

Comment: it will work for any type, "Persons[]" is a type in exactly the same way "Persons" is